# Date category construction

Tags: r, date

I am trying to make date categories "dat_cat" using the below sample dataframe. Although, I am getting the date categories I am getting the following error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date_cat, value = numeric(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 8
What can I do to avoid this error and in fact why am I getting it?

```
id <- c(3,3,6,6,4,4,3,3)
date <- c("2017-1-1", "2017-3-3", "2017-4-3", "2017-4-7", "2017-10-1", "2017-11-1", "2018-3-1", "2018-4-3")
date_cat <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
measurement <- c(10, 13, 14,13, 12, 11, 14, 17)
myData <- data.frame(id, date, measurement)
myData$date1 <- as.Date(myData$date)
myData

date_cat <- NA
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 < "2017-01-01")] <- 0

myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= "2017-01-01" & myData$date1 <= "2017-06-30")] <- 1
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= "2017-07-01" & myData$date1 <= "2017-12-31")] <- 2
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= "2018-01-01" & myData$date1 <= "2018-06-30")] <- 3

#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date_cat, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 8

myData
  id      date measurement      date1 date_cat
1  3  2017-1-1          10 2017-01-01        1
2  3  2017-3-3          13 2017-03-03        1
3  6  2017-4-3          14 2017-04-03        1
4  6  2017-4-7          13 2017-04-07        1
5  4 2017-10-1          12 2017-10-01        2
6  4 2017-11-1          11 2017-11-01        2
7  3  2018-3-1          14 2018-03-01        3
8  3  2018-4-3          17 2018-04-03        3
```

Comment: Rather than just `date_cat <- NA`, try `myData$date_cat <- NA` to first create the column of all NA values inside the data.frame. Otherwise that `date_cat` variable isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help in addition to @MrFlick great suggestion, remember that for dates even in comparison you have to format them as `as.Date()`:

```
id <- c(3,3,6,6,4,4,3,3)
date <- c("2017-1-1", "2017-3-3", "2017-4-3", "2017-4-7", "2017-10-1", "2017-11-1", "2018-3-1", "2018-4-3")
date_cat <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
measurement <- c(10, 13, 14,13, 12, 11, 14, 17)
myData <- data.frame(id, date, measurement)
myData$date1 <- as.Date(myData$date)
myData

myData$date_cat <- NA
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 < as.Date("2017-01-01"))] <- 0

myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= as.Date("2017-01-01") & myData$date1 <= as.Date("2017-06-30"))] <- 1
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= as.Date("2017-07-01") & myData$date1 <= as.Date("2017-12-31"))] <- 2
myData$date_cat[which(myData$date1 >= as.Date("2018-01-01") & myData$date1 <= as.Date("2018-06-30"))] <- 3
```

Output:

```
  id      date measurement      date1 date_cat
1  3  2017-1-1          10 2017-01-01        1
2  3  2017-3-3          13 2017-03-03        1
3  6  2017-4-3          14 2017-04-03        1
4  6  2017-4-7          13 2017-04-07        1
5  4 2017-10-1          12 2017-10-01        2
6  4 2017-11-1          11 2017-11-01        2
7  3  2018-3-1          14 2018-03-01        3
8  3  2018-4-3          17 2018-04-03        3
```

Comment: consider using `findInterval` eg `transform(myData,date_cut = findInterval(myData$date1,as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-06-30","2017-12-31", "2018-06-30"))))`